# Why are there so many bullies on SE sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

The moment you post a question that they either misread or misunderstand on their own accord they start to downvote and vote close furiously.

Even if your question has a single word in the subject same as some other subject its marked as duplicate without reading the detail of the question.

Its like having a dumb king who has you executed because he misheard something.

Most of the time even though you clear their doubts they'd not relent and undo the downvotes

Its almost like bullying people online give them a sense of superiority over their real life insecurities.

Sometimes they'd just downvote without giving any reasons like a dictatorship, while there only merit is they've spent more time on SE so they have more points and thus more power which they openly misuse

But this costs users like me loss of learning from SE and a bad experience overall.

Comment: You can't possibly know why people are down voting. Assuming it's because they are mean is short sighted. Badly phrased, unclear questions are bad for the health of the sites. If you wish your questions to be better received, do a better job of asking them the first time.

Comment: Do you remember why you became involved with these sites in the first place? Was it perhaps the high quality content? If so, how do you think we manage to keep the quality high? This _can be_ a fun place to learn, but not in the expense of our quality standards.

Comment: Insulting and casting aspersions over a large groups of people with broad generalities isn't going help anyone learn how to improve their experience on Stack Exchange.  I don't suspect you are actually looking for an *answer* to your *question*.  Please see our [Be Nice policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and if you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail. Thank you.

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close is not bullying. Understand this, and your experience on SE will be much nicer.

Comment: Oh, dear... It's always better to raise a very specific issue on each site's meta with clear examples of bullying and insulting. Moderators can see deleted comments and they can notice what's happened. Generally, it is wrong to assume all of downvoters and close-voters are bullies. If you find them, you can privately contact moderators if you don't want to raise the issue publicly. You will see the option **in need of moderator intervention** on the **flag** button. Use it wisely and to your advantage.

Comment: You asked (afaict) one question that was likely to involve discussions, which is specifically off topic.  Worse yet, you tagged it java and c++, pointing a spotlight on it for two communities that are regularly besieged with bad, off topic questions.  Hell, I wouldn't touch the C++ tag without asbestos gloves (I'll risk the cancer).  Lots of people free with downvotes saw your question and acted appropriately.  Bad luck on your part.  You might want to review the tour on SO in order to re-acquaint yourself with what is and is not on topic.  Also, the [meta-tag:faq] might be relevant for you.

Comment: How many users that read this know, or have interacted with you? You just go ahead and insult everyone and you think they're the bully?

Comment: @Rubisco calm down , I've not generalised yet, I just said many I did not say all or everyone even didn't targeted anyone personally so please do not misread and inflame. thank you

Comment: Also this show is now over , I do not wish to continue discussing this any further , and would abide to guidlines, please end this discussion and lock/delete/close the question whichever is appropriate

Comment: @Allahjane If you want this question deleted, you can flag it and leave a message to a moderator. Try to be as specific as possible. Good luck.

Answer (score 17):

I think you are wrong. There are indeed some bullies on Stack Exchange, but we try to find them and suspend them.

The majority of users are genuinely trying to make something beautiful on their site. They are confronted with users who don't give anything towards that and just want an answer. They destroy everything the site stands for. If such a user meets a user that actually cares about the site, things sometimes heat up a little.

Questions are closed and downvoted to keep the site quality high. Often this is seen as bullying, which it isn't. It is a way to learn to ask better questions. If you learn from it, improve the way you participate on the site, you will see it is not all too bad here.

Comment: I know, I'm not generalising or painting all admins the same. But in the same way not all non - admin users want to destroy and deface the site. My complaint is about the ones who do not wish to explain their action to the newbies because they have that " too superior to talk with peasants " kind of mentality. When I get a answer I'm looking for I press accept and upvote the answer, often times I'd reply with a comment praising the answer and sharing results.

Comment: You assume you know what someone else thinks. If I am reviewing 20-30 posts I don't like to comment with the OP of every post complaining I closed a question.

Comment: You are making assumptions again, about why people don't explain their actions. I've seem people stop from explaining after several bad interactions with people they have tried to help in this manner, @Allahjane.

Comment: @Allahjane people downvoting and voting to close your questions are (in most cases) not "admins", they are normal users like you.

Comment: @Allahjane because of how our sites work, every user has a part in site administration. In fact, voting, particularly down voting, is part of this administration. Remember, downvotes are not personal attacks. You shouldn't take them as a punishment.

Comment: @Oded "You are making assumptions again" well thats what I'm left with if nobody responds when I ask what is wrong in the question.

Comment: @Cai Allahjane isn't complaining about admins...

Comment: @Catija read the first comment here

Comment: @Allahjane No, you have the help center, thousands of questions on meta about how to ask good questions, if your question is closed, it's for an explained reason, etc.  You have more than enough information given to you about how to ask a good quesiton.  If you choose not to take advantage of that, that's on you.

Comment: @all Alright alright I got the lesson , now please relent and lock this question. Thanks for guiding me

Comment: Bullying online is real, and SE is not exempt. What the OP was complaining about; however, is not bullying, but sarky comments and anonymous downvoting.

Comment: @Allahjane While you asked the question, it doesn't belong to you, so you shouldn't dictate if it's closed or not.